# What is the M4-based text format used in the TUG Interviews book?

Tags: tools

The files used to prepare the TUG interviews book, [Tex People: Interviews from the world of Tex](http://tug.org/store/texpeople/), contains examples such as http://dw2.tug.org/ivbook/trunk/levien.m4, which begins

```
dnl $Id: rahtz.m4 265 2009-05-17 13:40:50Z dwalden $
define([[_date]],[[2009-05-16]])dnl
define([[_intervieweename]],[[Raph Levien]])dnl
define([[_intervieweeinitials]],[[RL[[]]_tinyspace()]])dnl
dnl
define([[_interviewername]],[[Karl Berry]])dnl
define([[_interviewerinitials]],[[KB]])dnl
dnl
define([[_interviewerbname]],[[Dave Crossland]])dnl
define([[_interviewerbinitials]],[[DC]])dnl

_header(levien.jpg,[[Raph Levien is a programmer with a special interest
in graphics applied to type.  He is also a typeface designer.  He holds
several patents and is a past maintainer of Ghostscript.]])
```

and ends:

```
_texonly(\bigskip)
_par _noindent Last, this is a screenshot of _link(http://fontforge.sf.net,
FontForge), which I used to put all the shapes together into a font, and
produce _Tone and OpenType font files.

_texonly(\medskip)
_noindent
_imageonly(levien-fontforge.png,width=.86\hsize)

_quotationstop

_footer
```

It is reminiscent of some hybrid of [Gnu M4](http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/) and Texinfo — what is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's indeed [GNU m4](http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/). One reason to choose it was to produce both HTML and LaTeX output:

- [texdefs.m4](http://dw2.tug.org/ivbook/trunk/texdefs.m4) is the definition file for TeX output
- htmldefs.m4 is the definition file for TeX output

You can read about that, also about technical m4 details, in: [TeX People: The TUG interviews project
and book](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb30-2/tb95berry-interviews.pdf).

Comment: That's an excellent link.  It seems somehow wrong to use a macro language to preprocess a macro language...